# Given heading, pitch, bank of point A on a plane and an offset to point B, how do I calculate the heading, pitch, bank of point B on the same plane?

Tags: math, matrix, vector, acceleration

I have the heading, pitch, and bank from a sensor in the center of an entity (point A), and I want to be able to calculate the heading, pitch, and bank of another point of the entity (point B). If I know the offset from point A to point B, how do I do this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a math question and not a programming problem.

Comment: At first I thought you were looking for https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463790/35416 but then the "on the same plane" (airplane?) and your use of "entity" suggests you might have two points on one aircraft. But what would the heading of a point even mean? Statically, the direction in which it is pointing doesn't make sense for a single point, you need an oriented line for that. Dynamically the direction in which something is moving should be the same for all points of the craft, unless you're changing its shape. Also, devlin is right, this belongs to math exchange but please reword to clarify